# Angular update from 14 to version 15 and now ng test gets 'No specs found'

Tags: angular, karma-jasmine

I have updated my Angular 14 app to Angular 15.1.4 app.  This app was created with Angular 4 and updated to each subsequent version.

'ng serve' builds and launches the app.  I ended up deleting .browserslistrc, because of a message when I launch serve and test.  Running 'ng test', I get 'No specs found', even though I should have 100's of tests.  The tests worked in version 14.  The message in the test browser is:

```
Incomplete: No specs found, , randomized with seed 89005
```

The  message on the command line is:

```
> ng test
√ Browser application bundle generation complete.
11 02 2023 14:29:13.412:WARN [karma]: No captured browser, open http://localhost:9876/
11 02 2023 14:29:13.429:INFO [karma-server]: Karma v6.4.1 server started at http://localhost:9876/
11 02 2023 14:29:13.430:INFO [launcher]: Launching browsers Chrome with concurrency unlimited
11 02 2023 14:29:13.436:INFO [launcher]: Starting browser Chrome
11 02 2023 14:29:18.071:INFO [Chrome 109.0.0.0 (Windows 10)]: Connected on socket rK2xPAWwWBFkQCuuAAAB with id 43283367
Chrome 109.0.0.0 (Windows 10): Executed 0 of 0 SUCCESS (0.004 secs / 0 secs)
TOTAL: 0 SUCCESS
```

I'm no expert in the workings of karma.  It just works.  I compared a newly created version 15 app that test worked, so I removed loading the karma config file in the angular.json file, but still no Specs.  I'm not seeing any apparent warnings or errors messages.  I'm at a lost of what to do next to get testing to work again.

The GitHub project can be found: https://github.com/PHuhn/Net.Incident4/tree/main/net-incident

Comment: Hi @Phil Huhn
I too have upgraded Angular recently from v14 to v15, so i have a query, should we update the versions of all the karma & jasmine related packages that are present in package.json, if we are upgrading Angular ? Or is it better to not change them?

Comment: Also, as you too have upgraded from 14 to 15 angular, you'd have done MDC migration, could you please let me know how did you resolve the TODO(mdc-... comments, like how can we know what we should modify in the css selectors and its blocks, and how can we really know what should we replace the existing class with mat mdc specific equivalent class? Any documentation?

Answer (score 19, accepted):

I looked more at the angular.json file in the working new Angular 15 application.  I had to do 2 things:

1. remove the "main"
2. change the "polyfills"

Changed from:

```
   "options": {
     "main": "src/test.ts",
     "polyfills": "src/polyfills.ts",
     "tsConfig": "tsconfig.spec.json",
```

Changed to:

```
   "options": {
     "polyfills": [
       "zone.js",
       "zone.js/testing"
     ],
     "tsConfig": "tsconfig.spec.json",
```

Comment: Amazing!
Removing the "main" (and adding "zone.js/testing") did the trick. Was going mad why Karma complained about SCSS after upgrading to Angular 15. I kept using our custom polyfills.ts though! 
`"polyfills": [
"src/polyfills.ts",
"zone.js/testing"
]`

Comment: @phil-huhn I think you should mark your answer as the correct one

Comment: hmmm, if we take out "main", is complains that we need a "main".  If I change polyfills to an array of strings, it complains polyfills must be a string???

Answer (score 2):

Phil Huhn's [solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/75429763/12360418) helped me as well. I created a new Angular 16 project and compared it with my own project. Apparently Angular no longer uses the `test.ts` file.

In addition to Phil's answer, it's worthwhile to note that you can safely remove the test.ts file and any other references to it. I had it listed in `tsconfig.spec.json` under the `files` array.